# BufferedImage pixel value issue

Tags: java, colors, pixel, bufferedimage

We are trying to get the rgb values of a pixel in a buffered image using getRGB(x,y).  Here is our code:

```
public Color getColor(Point p, BufferedImage image){
    int rgb = image.getRGB(p.x,p.y);
    Color c = new Color(rgb);
    return c;
}
```

But all we are getting for c is (255,0,0) and when we check the value of RGB we get -65536.  We have looked around and seen lots of bit shifting solutions but none have worked.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wPQe.jpg is an example of the frame.  We were clicking on the green. Any ideas?

private void initFrameGrabber(String videoDevice, int inWidth, int inHeight, int channel,
            int videoStandard, int compressionQuality) throws V4L4JException {
        videoDev = new VideoDevice(videoDevice);

```
    DeviceInfo deviceInfo = videoDev.getDeviceInfo();

    if (deviceInfo.getFormatList().getNativeFormats().isEmpty()) {
      throw new ImageFormatException("Unable to detect any native formats for the device!");
    }
    ImageFormat imageFormat = deviceInfo.getFormatList().getNativeFormat(0);

    frameGrabber = videoDev.getJPEGFrameGrabber(inWidth, inHeight, channel, videoStandard,
            compressionQuality, imageFormat);

    frameGrabber.setCaptureCallback(new CaptureCallback() {
        public void exceptionReceived(V4L4JException e) {
            System.err.println("Unable to capture frame:");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        public void nextFrame(VideoFrame frame) {
            long before = System.currentTimeMillis();
            frameImage = frame.getBufferedImage();
            frame.recycle();
            processAndUpdateImage(frameImage, before);
        }
    });

    frameGrabber.startCapture();

    width = frameGrabber.getWidth();
    height = frameGrabber.getHeight();
}
```

Comment: This code should work. Is the pixel you are trying to read not red?

If not, from where do you get the image? Any chance it has some exotic color model?

Comment: *"Any ideas?"* Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) & link to the image (preferably small in byte size) at an image upload site.

Comment: The pixel we're clicking is green.  The image is frame from an svideo feed.  I've added the frame grabbing code to the main post

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see the problem in the image linked.  The RGB values are less than 0, but form valid colors.

#### Screenshot

[image: Image Test]

#### Source

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import java.net.URL;

class ImageTest {

    public static int getRGB(int x, int y, BufferedImage image) {
        return image.getRGB(x,y);
    }

    public static Color getColor(int x, int y, BufferedImage image) {
        int rgb = image.getRGB(x,y);
        Color c = new Color(rgb);
        return c;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(
            new URL("http://i.imgur.com/WMfeU.png"));
        int w = bi.getWidth();
        int h = bi.getHeight();

        final BufferedImage bi2 = new BufferedImage(
            w,
            h,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        for (int x=0; x<w; x++) {
            for (int y=0; y<h; y++) {
                int rgb = getRGB(x,y,bi);
                if (x%20==0 && y%20==0) {
                    System.out.println(getColor(x,y,bi));
                }
                bi2.setRGB(x,y,rgb);
            }
        }

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bi2)));
            }
        });

    }
}
```

#### Output

```
java.awt.Color[r=115,g=148,b=77]
java.awt.Color[r=110,g=146,b=74]
java.awt.Color[r=111,g=147,b=77]
java.awt.Color[r=106,g=142,b=72]
java.awt.Color[r=106,g=141,b=73]
java.awt.Color[r=107,g=139,b=74]
java.awt.Color[r=75,g=95,b=46]
java.awt.Color[r=72,g=60,b=46]
java.awt.Color[r=108,g=92,b=79]
java.awt.Color[r=56,g=47,b=40]
java.awt.Color[r=32,g=28,b=27]
java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]
java.awt.Color[r=104,g=79,b=59]
java.awt.Color[r=122,g=91,b=62]
java.awt.Color[r=60,g=61,b=47]
java.awt.Color[r=61,g=77,b=40]
java.awt.Color[r=103,g=134,b=66]
java.awt.Color[r=110,g=137,b=68]
java.awt.Color[r=111,g=138,b=69]
java.awt.Color[r=110,g=141,b=73]
java.awt.Color[r=114,g=146,b=73]
java.awt.Color[r=116,g=148,b=75]
java.awt.Color[r=115,g=147,b=74]
java.awt.Color[r=113,g=145,b=72]
java.awt.Color[r=113,g=147,b=73]
java.awt.Color[r=111,g=144,b=73]
java.awt.Color[r=114,g=147,b=76]
java.awt.Color[r=107,g=140,b=71]
java.awt.Color[r=110,g=142,b=75]
java.awt.Color[r=108,g=138,b=74]
java.awt.Color[r=73,g=92,b=46]
java.awt.Color[r=71,g=61,b=49]
java.awt.Color[r=111,g=93,b=81]
java.awt.Color[r=31,g=31,b=29]
java.awt.Color[r=36,g=36,b=36]
java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]
java.awt.Color[r=103,g=78,b=56]
java.awt.Color[r=84,g=53,b=32]
java.awt.Color[r=58,g=58,b=46]
java.awt.Color[r=69,g=80,b=48]
java.awt.Color[r=106,g=136,b=66]
java.awt.Color[r=108,g=138,b=68]
java.awt.Color[r=106,g=136,b=66]
java.awt.Color[r=109,g=139,b=67]
java.awt.Color[r=117,g=147,b=75]
java.awt.Color[r=114,g=146,b=73]
java.awt.Color[r=113,g=145,b=72]
java.awt.Color[r=116,g=150,b=76]
java.awt.Color[r=112,g=146,b=72]
java.awt.Color[r=112,g=145,b=74]
java.awt.Color[r=111,g=144,b=73]
java.awt.Color[r=111,g=144,b=75]
java.awt.Color[r=109,g=142,b=73]
java.awt.Color[r=107,g=139,b=74]
java.awt.Color[r=75,g=94,b=48]
java.awt.Color[r=70,g=57,b=48]
java.awt.Color[r=96,g=79,b=69]
java.awt.Color[r=63,g=54,b=45]
java.awt.Color[r=61,g=52,b=45]
java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]
java.awt.Color[r=100,g=79,b=62]
java.awt.Color[r=125,g=88,b=69]
java.awt.Color[r=59,g=59,b=47]
java.awt.Color[r=69,g=80,b=50]
java.awt.Color[r=107,g=137,b=67]
java.awt.Color[r=107,g=137,b=67]
java.awt.Color[r=107,g=134,b=63]
java.awt.Color[r=110,g=140,b=68]
java.awt.Color[r=114,g=144,b=70]
java.awt.Color[r=119,g=149,b=75]
java.awt.Color[r=113,g=145,b=72]
java.awt.Color[r=115,g=147,b=74]
java.awt.Color[r=112,g=144,b=71]
java.awt.Color[r=112,g=146,b=72]
java.awt.Color[r=111,g=144,b=73]
java.awt.Color[r=108,g=141,b=72]
java.awt.Color[r=111,g=142,b=74]
java.awt.Color[r=113,g=144,b=77]
java.awt.Color[r=73,g=92,b=46]
java.awt.Color[r=68,g=61,b=45]
java.awt.Color[r=180,g=153,b=136]
java.awt.Color[r=61,g=52,b=45]
java.awt.Color[r=59,g=52,b=44]
java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]
java.awt.Color[r=96,g=75,b=54]
java.awt.Color[r=129,g=90,b=59]
java.awt.Color[r=63,g=63,b=51]
java.awt.Color[r=59,g=68,b=39]
java.awt.Color[r=102,g=132,b=62]
java.awt.Color[r=107,g=137,b=65]
java.awt.Color[r=107,g=137,b=65]
java.awt.Color[r=111,g=141,b=69]
java.awt.Color[r=115,g=145,b=73]
java.awt.Color[r=114,g=144,b=70]
java.awt.Color[r=112,g=144,b=71]
java.awt.Color[r=115,g=147,b=74]
java.awt.Color[r=113,g=145,b=72]
java.awt.Color[r=111,g=145,b=71]
java.awt.Color[r=110,g=143,b=72]
java.awt.Color[r=110,g=143,b=74]
java.awt.Color[r=110,g=143,b=74]
java.awt.Color[r=106,g=137,b=70]
java.awt.Color[r=76,g=89,b=45]
java.awt.Color[r=66,g=60,b=46]
java.awt.Color[r=104,g=82,b=71]
java.awt.Color[r=69,g=59,b=50]
java.awt.Color[r=70,g=60,b=51]
java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]
java.awt.Color[r=102,g=77,b=55]
java.awt.Color[r=132,g=93,b=62]
java.awt.Color[r=52,g=48,b=36]
java.awt.Color[r=58,g=63,b=40]
java.awt.Color[r=103,g=130,b=61]
java.awt.Color[r=104,g=134,b=62]
java.awt.Color[r=108,g=135,b=64]
java.awt.Color[r=114,g=141,b=70]
java.awt.Color[r=114,g=144,b=72]
java.awt.Color[r=119,g=149,b=75]
java.awt.Color[r=115,g=145,b=73]
java.awt.Color[r=121,g=153,b=80]
java.awt.Color[r=111,g=143,b=70]
java.awt.Color[r=115,g=147,b=74]
java.awt.Color[r=116,g=148,b=75]
java.awt.Color[r=107,g=138,b=68]
java.awt.Color[r=107,g=138,b=70]
java.awt.Color[r=107,g=136,b=69]
java.awt.Color[r=73,g=89,b=44]
java.awt.Color[r=64,g=62,b=50]
java.awt.Color[r=83,g=65,b=53]
java.awt.Color[r=80,g=66,b=55]
java.awt.Color[r=73,g=61,b=49]
java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]
java.awt.Color[r=103,g=79,b=55]
java.awt.Color[r=109,g=68,b=40]
java.awt.Color[r=69,g=66,b=51]
java.awt.Color[r=59,g=60,b=42]
java.awt.Color[r=101,g=131,b=61]
java.awt.Color[r=105,g=132,b=61]
java.awt.Color[r=106,g=133,b=62]
java.awt.Color[r=107,g=137,b=67]
java.awt.Color[r=115,g=143,b=69]
java.awt.Color[r=114,g=142,b=68]
java.awt.Color[r=115,g=143,b=69]
java.awt.Color[r=114,g=146,b=73]
java.awt.Color[r=110,g=142,b=69]
java.awt.Color[r=111,g=143,b=70]
java.awt.Color[r=109,g=141,b=68]
java.awt.Color[r=110,g=141,b=71]
java.awt.Color[r=107,g=138,b=70]
java.awt.Color[r=109,g=135,b=70]
java.awt.Color[r=75,g=86,b=43]
java.awt.Color[r=65,g=62,b=53]
java.awt.Color[r=78,g=59,b=42]
java.awt.Color[r=79,g=65,b=52]
java.awt.Color[r=76,g=64,b=52]
java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]
java.awt.Color[r=105,g=79,b=54]
java.awt.Color[r=116,g=72,b=45]
java.awt.Color[r=84,g=72,b=58]
java.awt.Color[r=57,g=58,b=40]
java.awt.Color[r=97,g=126,b=59]
java.awt.Color[r=98,g=128,b=56]
java.awt.Color[r=103,g=133,b=61]
java.awt.Color[r=105,g=132,b=61]
java.awt.Color[r=108,g=136,b=62]
java.awt.Color[r=112,g=142,b=68]
java.awt.Color[r=109,g=139,b=67]
java.awt.Color[r=113,g=143,b=71]
java.awt.Color[r=112,g=142,b=70]
java.awt.Color[r=110,g=142,b=69]
java.awt.Color[r=109,g=141,b=68]
java.awt.Color[r=107,g=138,b=68]
java.awt.Color[r=104,g=135,b=67]
java.awt.Color[r=99,g=131,b=64]
java.awt.Color[r=77,g=85,b=46]
java.awt.Color[r=64,g=57,b=51]
java.awt.Color[r=83,g=66,b=46]
java.awt.Color[r=80,g=66,b=55]
java.awt.Color[r=76,g=62,b=49]
java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]
java.awt.Color[r=106,g=82,b=58]
java.awt.Color[r=125,g=87,b=64]
java.awt.Color[r=106,g=88,b=74]
java.awt.Color[r=59,g=60,b=46]
java.awt.Color[r=92,g=123,b=55]
java.awt.Color[r=97,g=127,b=57]
java.awt.Color[r=101,g=128,b=59]
java.awt.Color[r=107,g=134,b=63]
java.awt.Color[r=109,g=136,b=65]
java.awt.Color[r=110,g=137,b=66]
java.awt.Color[r=105,g=135,b=63]
java.awt.Color[r=104,g=134,b=64]
java.awt.Color[r=106,g=138,b=65]
java.awt.Color[r=107,g=139,b=66]
java.awt.Color[r=107,g=138,b=68]
java.awt.Color[r=106,g=137,b=67]
java.awt.Color[r=105,g=136,b=68]
java.awt.Color[r=97,g=128,b=61]
java.awt.Color[r=73,g=80,b=39]
java.awt.Color[r=71,g=68,b=59]
java.awt.Color[r=84,g=67,b=57]
java.awt.Color[r=80,g=67,b=50]
java.awt.Color[r=82,g=69,b=53]
java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]
java.awt.Color[r=106,g=81,b=59]
java.awt.Color[r=112,g=78,b=53]
java.awt.Color[r=116,g=94,b=71]
java.awt.Color[r=59,g=57,b=45]
java.awt.Color[r=88,g=117,b=51]
java.awt.Color[r=88,g=156,b=69]
java.awt.Color[r=95,g=127,b=54]
java.awt.Color[r=100,g=130,b=58]
java.awt.Color[r=102,g=132,b=60]
java.awt.Color[r=103,g=133,b=61]
java.awt.Color[r=92,g=116,b=54]
java.awt.Color[r=123,g=101,b=87]
java.awt.Color[r=65,g=67,b=53]
java.awt.Color[r=101,g=134,b=65]
java.awt.Color[r=97,g=128,b=58]
java.awt.Color[r=101,g=134,b=65]
java.awt.Color[r=100,g=131,b=63]
java.awt.Color[r=98,g=129,b=62]
java.awt.Color[r=69,g=72,b=41]
java.awt.Color[r=88,g=76,b=64]
java.awt.Color[r=89,g=72,b=56]
java.awt.Color[r=83,g=70,b=53]
java.awt.Color[r=82,g=68,b=55]
java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]
java.awt.Color[r=103,g=78,b=56]
java.awt.Color[r=113,g=79,b=52]
java.awt.Color[r=123,g=93,b=67]
java.awt.Color[r=57,g=57,b=47]
java.awt.Color[r=48,g=145,b=50]
java.awt.Color[r=55,g=116,b=100]
java.awt.Color[r=87,g=124,b=55]
java.awt.Color[r=96,g=128,b=55]
java.awt.Color[r=104,g=134,b=62]
java.awt.Color[r=105,g=135,b=63]
java.awt.Color[r=94,g=104,b=51]
java.awt.Color[r=239,g=210,b=168]
java.awt.Color[r=74,g=63,b=45]
java.awt.Color[r=97,g=132,b=66]
java.awt.Color[r=97,g=130,b=61]
java.awt.Color[r=95,g=131,b=61]
java.awt.Color[r=91,g=126,b=58]
java.awt.Color[r=91,g=117,b=54]
java.awt.Color[r=56,g=54,b=29]
java.awt.Color[r=106,g=94,b=80]
java.awt.Color[r=81,g=65,b=50]
java.awt.Color[r=83,g=65,b=51]
java.awt.Color[r=79,g=66,b=50]
java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]
java.awt.Color[r=103,g=79,b=55]
java.awt.Color[r=104,g=80,b=56]
java.awt.Color[r=99,g=79,b=55]
java.awt.Color[r=47,g=49,b=38]
java.awt.Color[r=70,g=109,b=46]
java.awt.Color[r=81,g=113,b=50]
java.awt.Color[r=80,g=111,b=44]
java.awt.Color[r=97,g=126,b=59]
java.awt.Color[r=101,g=131,b=59]
java.awt.Color[r=105,g=135,b=63]
java.awt.Color[r=105,g=126,b=59]
java.awt.Color[r=39,g=17,b=3]
java.awt.Color[r=140,g=127,b=93]
java.awt.Color[r=100,g=133,b=64]
java.awt.Color[r=88,g=125,b=56]
java.awt.Color[r=81,g=120,b=57]
java.awt.Color[r=77,g=119,b=55]
java.awt.Color[r=73,g=98,b=41]
java.awt.Color[r=53,g=52,b=34]
java.awt.Color[r=89,g=67,b=56]
java.awt.Color[r=84,g=67,b=51]
java.awt.Color[r=84,g=67,b=51]
java.awt.Color[r=77,g=64,b=48]
java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]
java.awt.Color[r=110,g=86,b=62]
java.awt.Color[r=106,g=82,b=56]
java.awt.Color[r=106,g=82,b=58]
java.awt.Color[r=43,g=42,b=40]
java.awt.Color[r=53,g=53,b=41]
java.awt.Color[r=54,g=56,b=45]
java.awt.Color[r=53,g=53,b=41]
java.awt.Color[r=53,g=64,b=32]
java.awt.Color[r=84,g=101,b=47]
java.awt.Color[r=92,g=109,b=54]
java.awt.Color[r=89,g=109,b=50]
java.awt.Color[r=93,g=115,b=53]
java.awt.Color[r=94,g=114,b=53]
java.awt.Color[r=96,g=116,b=55]
java.awt.Color[r=78,g=83,b=42]
java.awt.Color[r=58,g=55,b=46]
java.awt.Color[r=56,g=56,b=44]
java.awt.Color[r=50,g=50,b=42]
java.awt.Color[r=40,g=35,b=29]
java.awt.Color[r=91,g=74,b=56]
java.awt.Color[r=90,g=71,b=54]
java.awt.Color[r=84,g=68,b=52]
java.awt.Color[r=74,g=60,b=49]
```